# Set up coverage configuration on pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, code-coverage, pydev

I reinstalled Eclipse with pydev (2.0.0.2011040403) but the run configuration with "coverage" is missing from the debug and run menus. I am sure that option used to be there, how can I get it show up again?

[image]

Comment: Isn't code coverage just a view?

Comment: @John Giotta, The "code coverage results" is a view. If I have got this right, you need to run your program first with a code coverage configuration to get these results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This changed on PyDev 2.0, now, instead of a run as coverage, you have to open the code-coverage view (under the window > views menu) and select the 'enable code coverage for new launches' options -- after that, any launch (regular or unit-test) will be automatically traced by the code-coverage.

There's a small video with this feature (and some other things) at: http://pydev.org/video_pydev_20.html

Comment: Yes they have directly linked to unit-test on 2.0 now. After installing the coverage package separately it worked.